# db4 handler is not available

Tags: php, database-administration

[image: phpinfo part]

How can I add db4 into supported dba handlers?

I have some code which should work with dba functions. When I do `print_r(dba_handlers());` I see only 4 handlers. Why is db4 is not available?

Answer (score -1):

This link might help you ... looks as if it is a compile time option

http://www.php.net//manual/en/dba.installation.php

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers.